# MS Excel scientific notation (example: 2.231321654E+01)

Tags: excel, rounding, scientific-notation, vba

I am editing a legacy Visual Basic 6.0 program. It reads from a GPIB instrument and obtains a raw string in scientific notation. For example:

```
2.231321654E+01
```

Another line in the program processes that string so that it would be suitable for input into the spreadsheet:

`Round(2.231321654E+01, 1)` returns `22.3`

I want to have 2 decimal places:

`Round(2.231321654E+01, 2)` **should** return `22.31`, but NO, it returns `22.3`. Why?

**Another approach:**
I tried to bypass the `Round()` processing and have the program input the raw string directly into the spreadsheet. I still get `22.3`

**Yet another approach:**
I bypassed the program entirely and manually input `2.231321654E+01` into any cell in the spreadsheet. I still get `22.3`

**Summary:**
I want to write 2 decimal places into the spreadsheet. How do I do it? I think the original author manipulated the cell number properties to retain only up to one decimal place. How do I manipulate it? What should I look for in the code?

Comment: `Round(... , 3)` return 1 decimal place as well?

Comment: @ariel, Yes, even `Round(..., 19)` returns 1 decimal place.

Comment: have you checked the formatting of the spreadsheet itself?

Comment: @ariel: Yes, the spreadsheet formatting retains only 1 decimal place. I need to manipulate the spreadsheet formatting from within the code, because every time I start new readings, the program creates a new sheet which is blocked from manual editing of number formats.

Comment: Then you need to do is change the formatting programmatically.

Comment: @ariel: Exactly. That's what I'm asking in the *Summary* part of my question.

Comment: what vba version are you using? Or are you on VB6 using OLE ? Paste some of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably something like

```
MyCell.NumberFormat = "#.00"
```